# Ubuntu Server disrgards console-setup when rebooting in VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox, fonts, console

I found this weird behavior. In VirtualBox, Ubuntu Server 12.04 uses this font:

[image]

I find that hard to read. Now I can run `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` fine, and set the font to `Fixed`, then it looks like this:

[image]

That is also how it looks by default in VMWare; much better in my opinion. Interestingly, the boot manager font also looks like that (i.e. loads correctly).

`dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` correctly updates the `/etc/default/console-setup` file, but after a reboot, all settings are gone. For some reason, it doesn't load `console-setup`.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem might be? Or better yet, where I could start looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug:[Console font does not get set](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/632382), and you can see the patch from [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/console-setup/saucy/revision/119).It's been fixed in 12.10, but the patch haven't been ported back to 12.04 by now.

So you can fix it by creating the upstart job `/etc/init/console-font.conf` with the following content:

```
# console-font - set console font
#
# Set the console font, in case the similar udev rule races with Plymouth
# and thus fails to do it.

description "set console font"

start on starting plymouth-splash

task

exec /lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon
```

Answer (score 1):

See [ubuntu vivid disrgards-console-setup after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630118/) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/.

This problem seems to be caused by a mismatch in the naming of fonts
that console-setup expects vs what are in `/usr/share/consolefonts/`, and
thus copied to `/etc/console-setup/` when you pick a font to use (using
`dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`).

If you go to a console and do an `strace /lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon`,
you can see that it is trying to open fonts like this:

```
/etc/console-setup/Lat15-TerminusBold11x22.psf
```

But if you look in `/etc/console-setup/`, there are only a handful of
fonts in there (the ones you picked), and they look more like this:

```
/etc/console-setup/Lat15-TerminusBold22x11.psf.gz
```

One has height x width, and the other has width x height.

The problem can be fixed in a few ways.

(1) `/lib/udev/console-setup-tty` could be fixed - This is the more
permanent, upstream solution.

(2) You could manually change `/etc/default/console-setup`, reversing the
height and width in FONTSIZE.  This will need to be done each time you
change the fonts using `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.  But when the
machine reboots, that preference is kept.

(3) You could install the fonts that console-setup-tty expects.  This
is what I call the "overkill" option.  I did it like this:

In /etc/rc.local:

```
# install console fonts and then set up console
/etc/console-setup/fonts.sh install
/lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon
```

Create a script called `/etc/console-setup/fonts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

action=$1

srcdir="/usr/share/consolefonts"
parent="/etc/console-setup"
subdir="fonts"

case "$1" in
    install)
        # console fonts are not named properly in Ubuntu 15.04, compensate
        [[ -d $parent/$subdir ]] || mkdir $parent/$subdir
        for x in $( cd $srcdir ; ls -1 ) ; do
           # rearrange the two numbers from HHxWW to WWxHH
           y=$(echo "$x" | sed -e 's/^\([^-]*\)-\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)x\([0-9]*\).psf.gz/\1-\2\4x\3.psf.gz/g')
           # whether the pattern above matches or not, we'll be uncompressing here
           z=${y/.psf.gz/.psf}
           [[ ! -f $parent/$subdir/$z ]] && zcat $srcdir/$x > $parent/$subdir/$z
           [[ ! -L $parent/$z ]] && ln -sv $subdir/$z $parent/$z
        done
        ;;
    uninstall)
        rm -rf $parent/$subdir
        # only remove broken links (links to the fonts we removed above)
        rm $(find -L $parent -type l)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$(basename $0) install|uninstall"
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

For a quick pragmatic solution, I'd do #2, with a comment in the file that
it may be need to be re-done if you choose a different font (assuming the
comment does not also get overwritten).

But #3 works well with minimal fuss or mess.