# ubuntu vivid disrgards-console-setup after reboot

Tags: 15.04, systemd, virtual-console

An earlier question at [Ubuntu Server disrgards console-setup when rebooting in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328463/) relates to Ubuntu version 12.  The (one) answer talks about installing an upstart job in `/etc/init/console-font.conf`.

I have Ubuntu version 15, on a physical machine not a virtual one (although that possibly isn't relevant).  That file exists, but of course Ubuntu 15 boots with systemd not upstart and the upstart job is completely ignored.

So what's the fix for this problem for Ubuntu version 15 with systemd?  How do I get Ubuntu to retain the font set with `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` over a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/
and [Ubuntu Server disrgards console-setup when rebooting in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328463/)

This problem seems to be caused by a mismatch in the naming of fonts
that console-setup expects vs what are in `/usr/share/consolefonts/`, and
thus copied to `/etc/console-setup/` when you pick a font to use (using
`dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`).

If you go to a console and do an `strace /lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon`,
you can see that it is trying to open fonts like this:

```
/etc/console-setup/Lat15-TerminusBold11x22.psf
```

But if you look in `/etc/console-setup/`, there are only a handful of
fonts in there (the ones you picked), and they look more like this:

```
/etc/console-setup/Lat15-TerminusBold22x11.psf.gz
```

One has height x width, and the other has width x height.

The problem can be fixed in a few ways.

(1) `/lib/udev/console-setup-tty` could be fixed - This is the more
permanent, upstream solution.

(2) You could manually change `/etc/default/console-setup`, reversing the
height and width in FONTSIZE.  This will need to be done each time you
change the fonts using `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.  But when the
machine reboots, that preference is kept.

(3) You could install the fonts that console-setup-tty expects.  This
is what I call the "overkill" option.  I did it like this:

In /etc/rc.local:

```
# install console fonts and then set up console
/etc/console-setup/fonts.sh install
/lib/udev/console-setup-tty fbcon
```

Create a script called `/etc/console-setup/fonts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

action=$1

srcdir="/usr/share/consolefonts"
parent="/etc/console-setup"
subdir="fonts"

case "$1" in
    install)
        # console fonts are not named properly in Ubuntu 15.04, compensate
        [[ -d $parent/$subdir ]] || mkdir $parent/$subdir
        for x in $( cd $srcdir ; ls -1 ) ; do
           # rearrange the two numbers from HHxWW to WWxHH
           y=$(echo "$x" | sed -e 's/^\([^-]*\)-\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)x\([0-9]*\).psf.gz/\1-\2\4x\3.psf.gz/g')
           # whether the pattern above matches or not, we'll be uncompressing here
           z=${y/.psf.gz/.psf}
           [[ ! -f $parent/$subdir/$z ]] && zcat $srcdir/$x > $parent/$subdir/$z
           [[ ! -L $parent/$z ]] && ln -sv $subdir/$z $parent/$z
        done
        ;;
    uninstall)
        rm -rf $parent/$subdir
        # only remove broken links (links to the fonts we removed above)
        rm $(find -L $parent -type l)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$(basename $0) install|uninstall"
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

For a quick pragmatic solution, I'd do #2, with a comment in the file that
it may be need to be re-done if you choose a different font (assuming the
comment does not also get overwritten).

But #3 works well with minimal fuss or mess.

Comment: Thanks for this!  In Ubuntu 15.10 I found that it prepend "guess-" at the beginning when it should be "Uni2-".  I also don't seem to have any `UTF-8.acm` file which it also tries to load...

Comment: BTW, `setupcon` seems to immediately load the right font right after doing the configuration without doing any of these changes.  You just have to run it each time you reboot, though, and on each terminal.